# Drupal 8 : the cache is too big

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I have a D8 website migrated from a D7. As the database is now bigger, I have upgraded my hosting service, but it's still not enough.
Indeed, my 400 Mo DB is almost full everyday, so I have du clear the cache manually every time.

How can i set a max size for the database ? I've tried with this solution :
$settings['database_cache_max_rows']['default'] = 500;

It worked a little, but it still not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered flushing the cache on cron? Checkout the [CacheFlush](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheflush) module. You can automate the cache flush with rules or on cron jobs.